# How do I fix “for loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode” GCC error?

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc

I'm trying to solve but I don't know where a mistake.

```
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tell GCC to use the C99 standard (or later). Read the [GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) for your version of GCC for the flags to use.

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring your `i` variable inside the `for` loop. This is common in C++, but was added (surprisingly recently) in the C99 specification.

Move the declaration of your `i` variable outside of the `for` loop:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can tell GCC to compile your code in C99 mode:

```
gcc -std=c99
```

Or if you want to retain GCC-specific features, use:

```
gcc -std=gnu99
```

Comment: 1999 is recent for you ?)

Comment: Best would just be to pass to a more recent version of gcc which has even C11 as a default.

Comment: @JensGustedt Considering Visual Studio 2013 only implemented *some* of C99 features, I'd say C99 support is a recent event (not the spec being recent).

Comment: you said " **(not the spec being recent)** ". is " **spec** " an abbreviation for  " **specification** " ? @Jonathon Reinhart

Comment: @FadyHany Yes, "spec" is a [*clipping* of "specification"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spec#:~:text=(colloquial)%20Clipping%20of%20specification.). When I said "surprisingly recently in the C99 specification" I meant that compiler support for C99 is fairly recent, even though the spec(ification) is much older.